# Error 3080006:Transaction took too long in EOSIO blockchain

Tags: blockchain, eos

EOS uses the following methodology.

- nodeos (node + eos = nodeos) - the core EOSIO node daemon that can be
  configured with plugins to run a node.
- cleos
  (cli + eos = cleos) - command line interface to interact with the
  blockchain and to manage wallets.
- keosd (key + eos = keosd) -
  component that securely stores EOSIO keys in wallets.

When the system contract is deployed an error is thrown, 
While debugging using Nodeos following error log was found.

**Error Log**

```
 `Error 3080006: Transaction took too long`.
```

```sh
./cleos set contract eosio ../../unittests/contracts/eosio.system -p eosio  

Reading WASM from /mnt/d/wcc/work/xeniro/snapscale/unittests/contracts/eosio.system/eosio.system.wasm...
Publishing contract...
Error 3080006: Transaction took too long
Error Details:
deadline exceeded
```

Comment: Please share the system contract code?

Comment: Does the contract code satisfies the provided api functions ? and which version of dawn are you using

Answer (score 0):

Kindly set the BIOS boot sequence for the version you are using under developer portal
Please check [Here](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/docs/bios-boot-sequence)

Under Dawn 4.1 , the following is successful

```
nodeos --max-transaction-time=1000 --resync
cleos create key  # for eosio.token 
cleos wallet import ... 
cleos create account eosio eosio.token ... 
cleos set contract eosio.token build/contracts/eosio.token 
cleos push action eosio.token create '[ "eosio", "10000000000.0000 SYS", 0, 0, 0]' -p 
eosio.token 
cleos push action eosio.token issue '[ "eosio", "1000000000.0000 SYS", "memo" ]' -p eosio

cleos set contract eosio build/contracts/eosio.system 
Reading WAST/WASM from build/contracts/eosio.system/eosio.system.wasm... 
Using already assembled WASM... 
Publishing contract... 
executed transaction: 901b98f873d67a084ed8e6ea50453e474935e44865ffcef42289e8878198a9fa  40440 byt
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I am using eos tag v1.8.2.

I mean, when I use the release version of the nodeos binary, I can deploy the `eosio.system` contract. But after reset, deploy the `eosio.system` contract with the debug version of the nodeos binary, which will report the above error.

I guess that because of the debug mode, the time to run this transaction is greater than the default single transaction runtime of eos. So when debugging, it is not suitable for deploying complex contracts.